# UICollectionView Reloading Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, reloaddata

A question regarding reloading data in your `UICollectionView`.

When using `reloadData` it only does this once any scrolling has finished. Then there is a small pause where the collection view freezes and cannot be interacted with until the new data is loaded in. How can I get around this?

For example, I would have a view comprised of maybe 10/20/30 items, each with an image and label. I then update my dictionary with new images and strings and then reload the view to add these new items.

Many thanks.

**EDIT**:

On closer inspection, its not the reloading that causes the pause, its some other code, where I fetch some data. Why might this freeze my view though when i am not even reloading it to make changes to it?

I am fetching this data from `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

EDIT 2:

Ok here is some basic code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self myMethodWithCompletionBlock:^(NSMutableDictionary *results, NSString *nextPageToken) {
        //No code in completion block is ever called when the method is called in the dispatch block! Regardless of what it is.
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post the details of what's being performed when you reloadData.  What's your data look like, what do the cells look like?

Comment: Oops, sorry added a little extra explanation. Say if you need more.

Comment: When you are fetching the data in `scrollViewDidScroll:`, are you fetching the data synchronously (doing the entire operation in the same thread before exiting the didScroll method)? If so, that could be blocking the UI momentarily, and you'd want to consider using `dispatch_async` for the fetch.

Comment: Just given your idea a try however I am having problems. I run my method which grabs new data inside my dispatch_async block however the method I call uses a completion, call back block where I get my results. However, the block contents are never called when run from inside this dispatch block. Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be great if we could see your latest code please.

Comment: Added some code, its pretty simple, I get a feeling it might be part of the Google API doing something, which is what I am using.